# Android SQL database Error while creating

Tags: java, android, mysql, email

I've made an E- Mail client for my Android Phone, and now I want to save the E- Mails in a SQLite database. But if I want to fill the Database only with test data, I this Error:

> E/SQLiteLog(21212): (1) near "TO": syntax error
>
> E/SQLiteDatabase(21212): Error inserting SUBJECT=test subject TO=emailadress2 FROM=emailadress1 CONTENT=test content
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TO": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MAIL(SUBJECT,TO,FROM,CONTENT) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
>
> (...)
>
> (1) near "FROM": syntax error
>
> E/Error(21212): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ID, FROM, TO, SUBJECT, CONTENT FROM MAIL WHERE ID = -1

I use the following code for the database:

MAINACTIVITY.java

```
public void dbCreate(View view){
    String from = "emailadress1";
    String to = "emailadress2";
    String subject = "test subject";
    String content = "test content";

    try {
        datasource.open();
        datasource.createEntry(from, to, subject, content);
        datasource.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Error", ex.toString());
            }
}
```

MYSQLiteHelper.java

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mail.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static final String TABLE_CREATE_MAIL = "CREATE TABLE MAILS (  ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FROM TEXT, TO TEXT, SUBJECT TEXT, CONTENT TEXT);";



public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    Log.i("Info", "OnCreate aufgerufen");
    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_MAIL);

}
```

DATASOURCE.java

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { "ID", "FROM",
        "TO", "SUBJECT", "CONTENT"};
public Entry createEntry(String from, String to, String subject, String content) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("FROM", from);
    values.put("TO", to);
    values.put("SUBJECT", subject);
    values.put("CONTENT", content);

    long insertId = database.insert("MAIL", null,
            values);


    Cursor cursor = database.query("MAIL",allColumns, "ID = " + insertId, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursorToEntry(cursor);
}
```

Comment: your table name is MAILS but you are inserting into MAIL that also may be an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TO` and `FROM` are [reserved word for SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Please try:

```
INSERT INTO MAIL(SUBJECT,`TO`,`FROM`,CONTENT) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

If you don't want to execute an arbitrary SQL command, you could just rename the columns to `TO_` and `FROM_`.

You could try to quote them like:

```
...
private String[] allColumns = { "ID", "`FROM`", "`TO`", "SUBJECT", "CONTENT"};
...
cv.put("`FROM`", from);
cv.put("`TO`", to);
...
```

Additionally: as commented by vinoth, your table name must be corrected (MAIL or MAILS)

Answer (score 0):

`FROM` and `TO` are `keywords` in `SQL`, so you should change your column name.

**The SQL standard specifies a huge number of keywords which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object**

[See this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is not an autoIncrement when creating your DataBAse..
and try this code when inserting data in the dataBase

```
 public long creatEntry(Srting id, String from,
    String to,String subject, String content) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); //ContentValues kima el bundle
cv.put("ID", id);
cv.put("FROM", from);
    cv.put("TO", to);
    cv.put("SUBJECT", subject);
    cv.put("CONTENT", content);

return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```